# Multiple queries in Riak

Tags: solr, riak, riak-search

I am querying my Riak database through the HTTP API like so:

```
/select?q=+build:2702168+hypervisors:500&q.op=and&wt=json&sort=tstart_int%20desc"
```

but all other query parameters than the first one gets ignored. So in this case, it returns all entries that fulfill `build:2702168`, but ignores `hypervisors:500`.

[This piece of documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/1.1.0/cookbooks/Riak-Search---Querying/), although old, shows that you can do regular solr multi-queries:

> The following example return documents containing the words “red” and
>   “blue” but not “yellow”.
>
> ```
> red AND blue AND NOT yellow
> ```
>
> The required ( + ) operator can be used in
>   place of “AND”, and the prohibited ( - ) operator can be used in place
>   of “AND NOT”. For example, the query above can be rewritten as:
>
> ```
> +red +blue -yellow
> ```

However, I can't find the same information in the latest Riak docs. Is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to a pretty old bug. [According to Basho's Ryan Zezeski](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nosql-databases/OTgv21wh09g/YBHd4KnU5RUJ):

> At one time I fixed it but it had to be reverted because it broke
>   rolling upgrade [1](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nosql-databases/OTgv21wh09g/YBHd4KnU5RUJ).  It has languished ever since.  To work around
>   explicitly put AND in the query.  E.g.
>   `q=nickname:Ring%20AND%20breed:Shepherd`

And as he says, doing this instead:

```
/select?q=build:2702168%20AND%20hypervisors:500&wt=json&sort=tstart_int%20desc
```

fixed the problem.